# Creating a web game, what technology to use?

Tags: web-applications

I am planning on creating a web game. I want this game to be able to run inside the browser, have decent performance and with a lot of continuous animations and input. I want this game to scale well, because I want it to get massive later on.

I thought about trying to create a java applet, but then I started to doubt. Is an applet the right choice? Should I take a look at javaFX? Or should I try flash or JavaScript? Or is there a technology which I haven't thought about yet?

Which technology would you recommend to create a web game?

Answer (score 5):

I really recommend you to use [Haxe](http://haxe.org/doc/intro?lang=en). Lots of website that runs web game, use this language/framework, thus I can't remember any at the moment. In fact it was designed for that.

Haxe combines JavaScript, Flash, PHP...

Edit: List of website running with Haxe: [here](http://haxe.org/com/projects). All Motion-twin website use Haxe.

Answer (score 3):

- Adobe Flash
- Adobe Flex
- Microsoft Silverlight

Answer (score 3):

I would never consider a Java applet for a web game. I would go for:

1. HTML + Javascript if the format allows
2. Adobe Flash
3. Microsoft Silverlight

Purely because the number of people that will be able to play your game with no installation.

Comment: Agreed. Java is nearly dead on the browser. They lost the game a while ago against Flash which can nowadays considered the de-facto standard. Silverlight is catching up, however, though Linux users have to wait a little until Moonlight 2 is finished.

Answer (score 0):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) probably suits your needs. It's easier to use than pure Java and comes with a bunch of nice libraries, and in the end you get a normal Java applet. Flash is also a good option for web games.

Comment: Processing? Really? I've never seen it used for anything other than tiny little one offs. You really think it can scale?

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't have to use their dinky little editor for everything. You can write Processing in Eclipse. I would say that any scalability problems they have are only with their IDE.

Comment: Javascript isn't the best way to make games.
There isn't a native API and there isn't classes.

Comment: M28, this is *Java*, not *Javascript*. Java is to Javascript as "car" is to "carpet."

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the criterias, is it 2D, 3D, text-mode? However, just make it as simple as possible, meaning that you should not over-think and over-do and just select a technology because of the "name" or whatever. Create an architecture and use whatever technology is suitable for your game.

A list of known good technologie

- Microsoft Silverlight
- Adobe Flash
- Java ( Applet )

and some more, but these are most common.

Answer (score 0):

Flash really is your best bet for this. I would stay away from newer technologies, such as silverlight or whatever else there is, simply because you don't see them very often at all and it would be a bad decision to try and learn how to do something that typically hasn't been done yet.

Especially because you mentioned scaling, flash uses [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), which can be as big or as small as you want, because their size isn't defined in pixels.

Java is feasible, but really, all the best web games are made using flash. Look at all the great games on websites like Kongregate, especially those produced by Armor Games. Once it gets big enough, it might be worth moving outside the browser to get over certain limitations, but that's very far in the future.

Comment: I doubt s?he meant image scaling with "scale well" :)

Comment: That might be the case, but you shouldn't be worried about making a game that "scales well" in that sense for your first game, or even your tenth game. There is a very large and steadily rounded curve to reaching that point, and there's a lot to learn between "first game ever" and "massively multiplayer flash game".

Comment: He shouldn't even be worried about anything other than single player for quite some time. If it isn't fun for one person, it won't be fun for 1,000.

Answer (score 0):

There's also:

- Pushbutton - open source flash engine.
- Game Maker - has a web component now, free for simple games, small cost for full engine.
- Wild Tangent - excellent graphics, higher cost though.
- Flixel - exciting new game engine for flash, free I believe.
- FlashPunk - new kid on the block, trying to compete with Flixel.

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript 3, you should start with flash, when you think you'll only need coding, you can use flex ;)